# FileNotFound exception using FileDialog

Tags: java

Everyone. I'm having some difficulty selecting a file with `FileDialog`. The dialog window is opening and I can select the file but then the code enters the `catch` block. Strangest thing is that IF the file is in my project folder there are no problems but if it is anywhere else I get `java.io.FileNotFoundException`. I used the debugger and saw that the exception that is caught occurs when the line `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);` is executed. Could somebody help me out because I am out of ideas. This is my code:

```
public void readData()
{
    try
    {
        FileDialog fileDialogBox = new FileDialog(mainWindow);
        fileDialogBox.setDirectory("C:\\Users\\Bobby\\Desktop\\");
        fileDialogBox.setVisible(true);
        File file = new File(fileDialogBox.getFile());
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        String lineOfText = "";
        while (scanner.hasNext())
        {
            lineOfText = scanner.nextLine();
            if (lineOfText.startsWith("//") || lineOfText.isEmpty())
            {

            }
            else
            {
                lineOfText = lineOfText.trim();
                Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(lineOfText);
                CD cd = new CD();
                cd.extractTokens(scanner2);
                addItem(cd);
            }
        }
        scanner.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException exception)
    {
        System.out.println(exception);
    }
    catch(IOException exception)
    {
        System.out.println(exception);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked what is the value of fileDialogBox.getFile()? maybe you just have to add path to the file: File file = new File(fileDialogBox.getDirectory()+"/"+fileDialogBox.getFile());

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment: you have to add path to the file name:

```
File file = new File(fileDialogBox.getDirectory() + "/" + fileDialogBox.getFile());
```